# Retrieve Duplicate Names (not numbers) in a Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am going to attach a link that showcases exactly what I am facing, with the code shown and descriptions of what should be happeneing.

See link: https://www.screencast.com/t/Zo3BH0i3v

In the event that you do not want to open that link, below I will explain the issue:

First and foremost, the code:

```
--Query Duplicate Document Names--

SELECT count(dcd.Name)'How Many Duplicates', dcf.Name 'Folder Name', dcf.ID 
            'Folder ID', dcd.ID 'Document ID', dcd.name 'Document Name', 
            'https://' + txtcityssldomainname + '/' + 'Admin/DocumentCenter/Folder/Index/' 
            + Cast (FK_FolderID AS VARCHAR) AS Link_To_Folder
FROM tblcitysettings tblcs, DocumentCenterDocuments dcd
JOIN DocumentCenterFolders dcf on dcf.ID = dcd.FK_FolderID
WHERE dcf.FK_Status IN (40,10) AND (dcd.FK_Status IN (40,10)) AND 
      (dcd.IsArchived IN (0)) AND (dcf.Name NOT IN ('Content', 'Design', 'Banners', 
      'MyAccount'))
GROUP BY dcf.Name, dcf.ID, dcd.ID, dcd.Name, 'https://' + txtcityssldomainname
         + '/' + 'Admin/DocumentCenter/Folder/Index/' + Cast (FK_FolderID AS VARCHAR)
HAVING count(dcd.Name) = 1
ORDER BY dcd.ID
```

What should happen, is it should return a count in the first column of "1" for every document that appears once. If the document appears more than once, it will concatenate those rows and show a value of how many appeared.

It is not working and I am completely at a loss.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Below is the Edited, Working copy:**

Note: I had realized that I was trying to merge a singular value in a column when there were other values that were not the same. Therefore, how could it merge those strings? I re-wrote the code to display the bare minimum.

```
SELECT count(dcd.DisplayName) 'Number of Duplicate Entries', dcd.DisplayName 'Document Name'

FROM DocumentCenterDocuments dcd

JOIN DocumentCenterFolders dcf on dcf.ID = dcd.FK_FolderID

where dcd.IsArchived IN (0) AND (dcd.FK_Status IN (40, 10)) AND (dcf.FK_Status IN (40, 10)) AND (dcf.Name NOT IN ('Content', 'Design', 'Banners', 'MyAccount'))

GROUP BY dcd.DisplayName

Having count(dcd.DisplayName) > 1
```

Thank you!

Comment: what DBMS are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (2017)

Comment: Resolved. Please read the updates in the initial question.

Comment: Instead of editing your question, it'd be better if you post your solution as an answer, and accepted it.